# failed to open stream: No such file or directory on Homestead environment

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php, homestead, laravel-artisan

I'm using homestead environment and the commmand line "php artisan -V" it doesn't work. I created my project with "laravel new test" so.. I want to think all my files are updated.

```
vagrant@homestead:~/Laracasts/test$ php artisan -V
PHP Warning:  require(/home/vagrant/Laracasts/test/bootstrap/autoload.php):         
failed to open stream: No such file or directory in         
/home/vagrant/Laracasts/test/artisan on line 16

Warning: require(/home/vagrant/Laracasts/test/bootstrap/autoload.php):     
failed to open stream: No such file or directory in 
/home/vagrant/Laracasts/test/artisan on line 16
PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required 
'/home/vagrant/Laracasts/test/bootstrap/autoload.php' 
(include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /home/vagrant/Laracasts/test/artisan on 
line 16

Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required 
'/home/vagrant/Laracasts/test/bootstrap/autoload.php' 
(include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /home/vagrant/Laracasts/test/artisan on 
line 16
vagrant@homestead:~/Laracasts/test$
```

.yaml file

---

```
ip: "192.168.10.10"
memory: 2048
cpus: 1
provider: virtualbox

authorize: ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

keys:
- ~/.ssh/id_rsa

folders:
- map: ~/Desktop/Arnau/dev/repositories/phpmyadmin
  to: /home/vagrant/phpmyadmin

- map: ~/Desktop/Arnau/dev/repositories/Laravel
  to: /home/vagrant/Laravel

- map: ~/Desktop/Arnau/dev/repositories/Laracasts
  to: /home/vagrant/Laracasts

sites:
- map: phpmyadmin.app
  to: /home/vagrant/phpmyadmin

- map: administracio.dev
  to: /home/vagrant/Laravel/administracio/public

- map: laracasts.dev
  to: /home/vagrant/Laravel/laracasts/public

databases:
- phpmyadmin
- administracio
- laracasts
```

And.. even my host file I added at the end.

```
192.168.10.10 administracio.dev
192.168.10.10 laracasts.dev
```

Next error after *php composer.phar install*

```
vagrant@homestead:~/Laracasts/test$ php composer.phar install
Loading composer repositories with package information
Installing dependencies (including require-dev) from lock file
Nothing to install or update
Generating optimized autoload files
> Illuminate\Foundation\ComposerScripts::postInstall
> php artisan optimize
PHP Warning:  require(/home/vagrant/Laracasts/test/bootstrap/autoload.php):     
failed to open stream: No such file or directory in     
/home/vagrant/Laracasts/test/artisan on line 16

Warning: require(/home/vagrant/Laracasts/test/bootstrap/autoload.php): 
failed to open stream: No such file or directory in 
/home/vagrant/Laracasts/test/artisan on line 16
PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required 
'/home/vagrant/Laracasts/test/bootstrap/autoload.php' 
(include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /home/vagrant/Laracasts/test/artisan on 
line 16

Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required     
'/home/vagrant/Laracasts/test/bootstrap/autoload.php' 
(include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /home/vagrant/Laracasts/test/artisan on 
line 16
Script php artisan optimize handling the post-install-cmd event returned 
with error code 255
vagrant@homestead:~/Laracasts/test$
```

Comment: Can you also post your homestead.yaml file?

Comment: I added more info

Comment: Try running composer install in the root of your test project. I'm guessing composer didn't compile the autoloader yet.

Comment: I used the command-line installation I found in here: https://getcomposer.org/download/

All settings correct for using Composer
Downloading...

Composer (version 1.4.1) successfully installed to: /home/vagrant/Laracasts/test/composer.phar
Use it: php composer.phar

vagrant@homestead:~/Laracasts/test$ php -r "unlink('composer-setup.php');"
vagrant@homestead:~/Laracasts/test$

But it still the same error.

Comment: have you RUN composer? Go into the directory in type `php composer.phar install` and see if that helps.

Comment: I added the error to my question because the message it's too long.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141978/discussion-between-arnau-guadall-and-douwe-de-haan).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After a lengthy discussion and debugging the problem became clear; the `bootstrap/autoload.php` file was missing.

The solution to this problem was inserting the code that should have been there ([found in bootstrap/autoload.php here](https://github.com/laravel/laravel)).

How the file ended up missing wasn't clear though.

Comment: Flagged as the link is dead and thus doesn't answer the question anymore